# MSQL Restore Errof

Tags: mysql

I am trying to restore an mysql database using
mysql -u root -p databasename < dumpfile.bak
I get this error
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.9, for Win64 (x86_64)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Ora' at line 1

The database is created and is correct looking at it "Show columns from table name" the dumpfile is in the mysql bin folder.

The dump file was created using `mysqldump -u root -p databasename > dumpfile.bak`
Here are the first few lines of the dumpfile:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.9, for Win64 (x86_64)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                      --disable-auto-rehash.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the first lines from your `dumpfile.bak` file. Also explain in detail how you have created the `dumpfile.bak` file.

Comment: if it is not ro big, load it into workbench this should show you te error

Comment: For some reason you have added the help page of the `mysql` command to your `dumpfile.bak` file. Please recreate the MySQL dump and verify that it contains actual SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, when progman talked about the dbfile, after I posted it, I took another look and found that it was not the correct version of the file. I thought the error was in the query not the file. Thanks for the help!!!!!